# Getting maps working in KitKat emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, maps, emulation, android-4.4-kitkat

A question I asked on Reddit, which it seems several other people would have liked answered, has elicited no response, so maybe the amazing Stackoverflow community can provide an answer?

I can get maps (and hence my mapping apps) working in a 4.1.2 emulator by creating a VM targetting "Google APIs (Google Inc.) API Level 16".

When I do the same thing for KitKat - "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API level 19", both my apps and the Google maps app itself load but where the map should be I just get a blank space.

I seem to have everything for Android 4.4 installed (according to the Eclipse SDK manager). Is it just me or is this a general problem with maps in the emulator?

Has anybody managed to get maps working in a Kitkat emulator? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: were Google-Play-Services up to date ?

Comment: A useful suggestion, thanks. Though ultimately it didn't make any difference to the problem, it will probably be relevant to getting the app to work on real KitKat devices. I had an earlier version imported into my workspace, with the newer one having over-written that in /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services. Still just a blank even with it unfortunately...

Comment: Small update - since changing the Google-play-services and recreating my VMs I get a useful message about "Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above". Another StackOverflow answer about that suggests checking "host gpu" option for the VM. Unfortunately that just causes the VM to crash (with no messages at all) when maps is launched.

Comment: i suggest you to use geny motion  emulator 
instead of creating new VM http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, Genymotion does not yet have a (non-experimental) 4.3 emulator, let alone 4.4 :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but I was able to install an older version of the Maps APK in an x86 KitKat emulator running in Windows and it appears to work fine.  (I do have the same issue you reported when targeting "Google APIs (Google Inc.) API Level 19".)